# Custom Keyboard - How to get maxLength InputView?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-custom-view, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I'm trying to make a custom Android Keyboard. I don't known how to get maxLength inputView (edittext) to prevent commit character if limited.  ( in EditorInfo class don't have maxLength property ). Someone help me please !

```
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
if (ic != null) {
    ic.commitText(String.valueOf(charCode), 1);
}
```

Comment: Could you post what you did so far and a example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank Ricardo A. I have edited it !

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible, since the limit of the editText is managed by the application where it is.